# Collision Normal in iOS7 SpriteKit Physics

Tags: ios7, game-physics, xcode5, sprite-kit

Does anyone know how to find or calculate the collision normal in SpriteKit. Coming from Box2D, there is a manifold  method that provides the normal information, but in SpriteKit framework, the SKPhysicsContact only provides a contact point.

I am using primitive objects, plane colliding with circle, circle/rectangle collisions and circle/custom shape collisions.

Could someone please point me to the Math on calculating surface normal using the collision contact point, that would be much appreciated.

Comment: What types of shapes are colliding? And are they edge-based collisions? Those will determine how you calculate the collision normal and make your question easier to answer.

Comment: I'm using primitive shapes, circles & rectangles mostly, but I do have a couple custom shapes with angled edges/planes(Think of custom shapes like the classic brick breaker paddle). So using the normal from the physics engine I should be able to calculate the reflection direction.

Answer (score 2):

**Update:** As of iOS 8, `SKPhysicsContact` has a [`contactNormal`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContact/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/SKPhysicsContact/contactNormal) property. However, the advice below may still apply, as a contact normal doesn't always do what you might want it to.

---

The collision normal calculated by Box2D [may not be a good estimate of the contact normal](http://www.iforce2d.net/b2dtut/collision-anatomy). This is true of the collision detection/resolution algorithms of many 2D physics engines, probably including SpriteKit's.

If you're looking to implement the classic Breakout-style paddle (where hitting the ball near the ends of the paddle deflects it more than hitting it near the middle), here are a couple of ideas:

1. Use an elliptical physics body for the paddle. (Even if your sprite art is mostly rectangular, the difference in geometry might not be noticeable to the player.) Or use a construction of multiple nodes, each with their own physics body, to compose a more complicated curvature from circles, rectangles, and ellipses.
2. Implement a post-collision handler ([`didEndContact:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKPhysicsContactDelegate_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SKPhysicsContactDelegate/didEndContact:) or [`didSimulatePhysics`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/SpriteKit/Reference/SKScene_Ref/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/SKScene/didSimulatePhysics)) and adjust the velocity of the ball after the collision. You can convert the contact point to (the paddle's) node coordinates, find the horizontal offset from the paddle's center, and use that to scale or rotate the ball's new velocity vector. (Note that if you're doing nontrivial vector math like this, you might find it convenient to convert to your vectors to `vector_float2` so you can use the hardware-accelerated vector math functions provided by the SIMD library.)

Comment: Thank you @rickster. I had thought about using multiple nodes. My Box2D version of a Brick Breaker game had multiple fixtures, which was also easy to break apart & change its shape on power up. What I need help with is to figure out how to calc surface normal using just the contact point and the colliding object circle or custom shape. I was using the colliding object center position & contact point to calculate normal vector but it was very buggy and not working as I had thought it would. If you know of any site that I could use to learn the MAth involved, please advise.

Answer (score 0):

`SKPhysicsContact` contains `contactNormal` vector property